# Showing $x+y>z$, where $x=\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{26}$, $y=\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{37}$, and $z=\sqrt{323}$. Is my idea corect?

Tags: inequality, radicals, square-numbers

> Let the numbers be $x=\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{26}$, $y=\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{37}$, and $z=\sqrt{323}$.  Show that $x+y>z$.

**MY IDEA**

So I thought if i write every number in a interval of 2 perfect square numbers.

[image]

Using this table we can write that $\sqrt{9}<\sqrt{10}<\sqrt{16}$, which basiclly means that $3<\sqrt{10}<4$

We can do this to all numbers and add them up. We can compare them easly after.

I just wanted to ask if my ideas and my way of thinking is corect. If not, can you help me solve this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: That seems to work

Comment: Yes It works for this problem. x>3+5=8 and y>4+6=10 then x+y>18 = sqrt(324)>sqrt(323)

Comment: If you look at your table you will probably spot where the numbers 10,26,17, 37 and 323 come from!

Comment: Now try 341 instead of 323. The left side squared is about 341.036, so this should be quite difficult.